# ExtJS 4 Two collapsible panels with splitter

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a container with two panels as it items. I want both panels to be collapsible (at the same time no one or only one panel can be collapsed) and if any panel is collapsed other panel should take all remaining space. Also I want to be able to resize both panels with [Ext.resizer.Splitter](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.resizer.Splitter).

I have tried different combinations of (h/v)box / border layout, but none of them works correctly.

It seems like [Ext.layout.container.Accordion](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.Accordion-cfg-multi) is what I need but, as I can see, it doest work with Ext.resizer.Splitter out of the box.

[Check this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/26ih)

*Also, I want to be able to collapse both panels with **single** Ext.resizer.Splitter, but as I can see its not available out of the box and I have to override it. Am I right?*

I'm using ExtJS version 4.2.1.

Comment: So you would like something like an [accordion](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/26iu) but with the ability to collapse all items?

Comment: @scebotari66 Yes, something like that, but with `Ext.resizer.Splitter`. Actually, I almost forgot about accordion layout! Maybe I can integrate it with splitter in some way...

Comment: If this question seems incorrect to you for any reason, then please write why. Dont just downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

```
Ext.application({
name: 'Fiddle',

launch: function () {

    Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
        height: 500,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        width: 500,
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
            align: 'stretch'
        },

        items: [{
            xtype: 'panel',
            reference: 'panel1',
            title: 'Top panel',
            collapsible: true,  // To allow collapse
            flex: 1,
            bodyStyle: 'background: #dadada',
            listeners: {
                collapse: function(){
                    this.up().down("[reference='panel2']").expand();
                }
            }
        }, 
        {
            xtype: 'splitter' 
        },
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            reference: 'panel2',
            title: 'Bottom panel',
            collapsible: true,  // To allow collapse
            flex: 1,
            bodyStyle: 'background: #999',
            listeners: {
                collapse: function(){
                    this.up().down("[reference='panel1']").expand();
                }
            }
        }]

    });
}});
```

Here `vbox` is used to set the panels vertically (the `flex` property tells them how much space to take from each other). The `collapsible` property set to true makes them collapsible. Then each panel has an event that expands the sibling panel when the target panel collapses. With this, at least one panel is always expanded and you can resize them with the splitter!

---

**Edit 1**:

The previous code sample isn't generic and does not react as expected if we set panels with `animCollapse: false`. A generic solution would look like the following:

```
// Our extended container
Ext.define('MyVboxContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',

    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },

    // We do the setup on initiating the component
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        var panelCount = 0;

        // For each child component
        this.items.forEach(function (comp) {

            // If the component is a panel
            if (comp.xtype === 'panel') {

                // We add an unique ref
                comp.reference = 'panel' + panelCount;

                // Increment the total number of panels
                panelCount++

                // And listeners for beforecollapse, collapse and expand
                comp.listeners = {
                    // On collpase, we track the last collapsed panel
                    'collapse': function () {
                        me.closedCount++;

                        me.lastClosed = this.reference;
                    },

                    // On expand we decrement the total number of panels collapsed
                    'expand': function () {
                        me.closedCount--;
                    },

                    // If this is the last panel being collapsed,
                    // we expand the previous collapsed panel
                    // Note: this cannot be done on the expand event
                    // if the panel has animCollapse: false
                    'beforecollapse': function () {
                        if (me.closedCount + 1 == me.totalPanels) {
                            me.down("[reference='" + me.lastClosed + "']").expand();
                        }
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        this.totalPanels = panelCount; // total number of panels
        this.lastClosed = null; // Last collapsed panel
        this.closedCount = 0; // How many panels we have closed

        console.log("Total panels are: " + this.totalPanels)

        this.callParent();
    }
});

Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        Ext.create('MyVboxContainer', {
            height: 500,
            width: 500,
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                animCollapse: false,
                title: 'Top panel',
                collapsible: true, // To allow collapse
                flex: 1,
                bodyStyle: 'background: #dadada'
            }, {
                xtype: 'splitter'
            }, {
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Middle panel',
                animCollapse: false,
                collapsible: true, // To allow collapse
                flex: 1,
                bodyStyle: 'background: #999'
            }, {
                xtype: 'splitter'
            }, {
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Bottom panel',
                animCollapse: false,
                collapsible: true, // To allow collapse
                flex: 1,
                bodyStyle: 'background: #999'
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Here we create an extended container that uses `vbox` layout to set the panels vertically. On `initComponent`, this container setups the existing children panels to always keep the **penultimate collapsed panel expanded**. You should modify the algorithm to suit your needs.

**Sidenote:** it isn't ideal to set variables on the view container. These variables should be moved into a controller.

Comment: First, thanks for the answer! This decision is generally suitable for me, but I was looking for a more universal solution, I will wait until the end of the bounty period and if more suitable solution does not appear I will reward you. And one remark - there is an error if one of the panels is collapsed and I try to collapse the second one.

Comment: I did not reproduce any error when testing my sample. Can you tell me which is the error? If you want an universal solution you should use a controller to listen the collapse/expand events of your panels and keep track of those that are closed. This way, you can enforce at least one panel open at any time by manually calling `panel.expand()` when collapsing the last open panel! I believe you could achieve the same solution with a custom plugin.

Comment: You can check error here - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2758. Just collapse first panel and then collapse second panel.

Comment: By more universal solution I mean override for box layout / splitter / whatever. Anyway, I really appreciate your answer!

Comment: It seems my solution is allergic to the `animCollapse: false` property that you added in both panels. Removing this will work as expected. I'll try to work around

Comment: Edited my answer. The new sample solves the error you were getting. It seems that we cannot expand a panel while we are collapse another with animations set to false.

Comment: Thanks! The only thing I want to offer is move code to fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote component, based on [Ext.resizer.Splitter](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.resizer.Splitter) code. Its allow to collapse both panels with single splitter.

Solution is abit raw, you can check it in [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/275b).

Answer (score 0):

> In ExtJs have **[spliter](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.6/#!/api/Ext.resizer.Splitter)**.

You can user inside your container. Here I have created an demo with **collapsible** panel.

Hope it will help you to solve your problem. [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/275p)

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
     height: 300,
     layout: {
         type: 'vbox',
         align: 'stretch'
     },
     width: 400,
     renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
     border: 1,
     items: [{
         xtype: 'panel',
         collapsible: true,
         title: 'First Panel',
         flex: 1
     }, {
         xtype: 'splitter',
         height: 20
     }, {
         xtype: 'panel',
         collapsible: true,
         flex: 1,
         maintainFlex: true,
         title: 'Second Panel'
     }]
 });
```

Comment: Myabe Ive missed something, but your answer seems like duplicate of accepted answer for me, but ignore this part of my question "at the same time no one or only one panel can be collapsed".

Comment: So you can put condition for at time only one panel can  be  collapsed in before collapse event. In before collapse event you can check if one already collapse than return false. So event will no t execute.

Comment: Yes, soltuion like this already described in the accepted answer. Have you read it?